# Two CodeIgniter App Session Overiding Eachother

Tags: codeigniter, session

so i have 2 ci app on my server(different project folder) and the session overiding each other when accessed with same browser.

i just notice this, because i think its gonna be different by default even the session variable name is same.
i find some problem here when im set_userdata and sess_destroy it applying to both of the app.
i use pretty much same variable on each other

```
                            $data_session = array(
                            'EMP_ID' => $data['EMP_ID'],
                            'EMP_FULL_NAME' => $data['EMP_FULL_NAME'],
                            'EMP_F_NUM' => $data['EMP_F_NUM'],
                            'EMP_EMAIL' => $data['EMP_EMAIL'],
                            'LEAD_STATUS' => $data['LEAD_STATUS'],
                            'BRANCH_ID' => $row_br['BRANCH_ID'],
                            'BRANCH_NAME' => $row_br['BRANCH_NAME'],
                            'BRANCH_CODE' => $row_br['BRANCH_CODE'],
                            'DEPART_ID' => $row_dep['DEPART_ID'],
                            'DEPART_NAME' => $row_dep['DEPART_NAME'],
                            'STATUSLOGIN' => "LOGIN",
                            'CONTINUE' => 'NEW'
                            );
                            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
```

how do i make it different from each other? do i need to make a different variable when set_userdata on each app?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are probably using the copy of an old project to create a new project. In doing so you also need to change the Config variables for sessions in the `application/config/config.php` file.

So you need to update one session name variable.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'second_project_session';
```

Comment: im using new ci that i got from https://codeigniter.com/download

the config is like this by default 
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

do i need to change that everytime i do a project ?

Comment: Try Change `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';` with `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session_project1';` and test.

Comment: If you are ruining two CI projects on the same server your `sess_cookie_name` values needs to be different so they have separate sessions